# Storing Iberico and Serano ham long-term

Tags: meat, storage-lifetime

What is the best method for storing unsliced Iberico and Serano ham?  Is there a 'recommended' temperature or humidity level that I should be aiming for?    How long will it last?

Comment: The above is assuming I haven't eaten it all beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

You can store a complete un-sliced Iberico or Serrano ham hanging it (with the hoof upwards) in a cold and dry place, away from direct light. The ham should be uncovered (no plastic, no paper or any kind of wrapping).

If you are going to keep it for a long time, you can rub the surface with a cloth impregnated with sunflower oil, especially the part of the leg where it joins with the hip.

In pre-crisis times I usually received two or three hams for Christmas, and I store them hanging in the pantry for months without getting spoiled.